# why does Microsoft visual studio keep ignoring changes made to the code and how do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to change the code in an HTML file and add two lines of code:

```
document.open()
document.write(year) //this was already here
document.close()
```

but when I run the code it ignores the changes and just gives me this when I use F12:

```
document.write(year)
```

Comment: You DO save the file after adding the new code, right?

Comment: yes I do save the file I have rebooted the program and the entire pc, opened up the file, checked, the changes were there, I ran it, it still ignored the changes. (help)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Browsers will cache plain HTML files, image files, script files, etc. and so they will ignore your changes.  In Chrome you can click the "ignore cache" button in the network section, or use CTRL-F5.  That's why JS files often have either a _versionnumber.js or .js?versionnumber=1 added so customers don't get old versions.